# How to use separable verb after a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: word-order, expression

How do you use a separable verb after a subordinating conjunction? I know that for inseparable verbs, they're just conjugated and dragged to the end of the subordinating clause, but what about this:

> You believe you see the essentials.

Is it translated as:

> Du glaubst, dass du dir das Wesentliche siehst an.

Or:

> Du glaubst, dass du siehst dir das Wesentliche an.

And also, what if you add a modal verb into the sentence? How do you translate "You believe you can see the essentials."? (i.e. where should *kannst* be positioned?)

Comment: FWIW, your German translation of the English sentence is slightly off in the first place and should rather be: 'Du glaubst, dass du das Wesentliche siehst.' 'Ansehen' implicates a more thorough and active action (look at) and not just a casual observation as in see/sehen.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for separable verbs is:

> Separable verbs are split only if the verb is used in second position in a main clause.

The general rule for word order is:

> Verbs are placed at the end of the sentence (in reverse order, compared to English), except for the conjugated verb in a main clause, which has to be in second position.

So:

> Du **kaufst** das Wesentliche **ein**.
>   Du kannst das Wesentliche **einkaufen**.
>   Du kannst das Wesentliche **eingekauft** haben.
>   Du kannst das Wesentliche **eingekauft** haben wollen.
>   ..., weil du das Wesentliche **einkaufst**.
>   ..., weil du das Wesentliche **einkaufen** kannst.
>   ..., weil du das Wesentliche **eingekauft** haben kannst.
>   ..., weil du das Wesentliche **eingekauft** haben wollen kannst.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence would be translated as

> Du glaubst, du siehst dir das Wesentliche an.

Or

> Du glaubst, dass du dir das Wesentliche ansiehst.

If you add a modal verb into the sentence your sentence could look like this

> Du glaubst, du kannst dir das Wesentliche ansehen.

But in this case your verb wouldn't be conjugated anymore.